# SignalR (.NET Core) problems with slow internet

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm using .NET SignalR in an online multiplayer game.

When a player leaves the game, I replace him with a robot so that other players can continue gaming.

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly MyService myService;

    public MyHub(MyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public string GetConnectionId() => this.Context.ConnectionId;

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await this.myService.HandlePlayerLeave(this.Context.ConnectionId); // replace player with robot
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

However, some players from countries with slow network connections are reporting that sometimes the game stops for them, experiencing the same behavior as if they had left the game, but they did not.

I have the following questions:

I don't understand why SignalR behaves the same way as when a user exits the game when someone has a very slow internet connection. In these cases, the users tell me that the connection never breaks up. Can someone explain this behavior?

How can I reproduce this behavior? I tried using throttling in the browser, but it didn't help.

How can I solve this problem and optimize the behavior for users with slow internet connections?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SignalR configuration** to change connection behaviors. Increase **ClientTimeoutInterval**, **HandshakeTimeout**, and **KeepAliveInterval** values to see if it meets your requirements. Each option description should be read carefully, as some of them depend on each other. check the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=dotnet) for **more options**.

```
services.AddSignalR().AddHubOptions<MyHub>(options =>
{
 options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
 options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45);
});
```

Also, I had the same issue uploading large files when someone was trying to upload a file with a low internet connection. By changing **kestrel server options** I was able to modify data rates.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
serverOptions.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate =
 new MinDataRate(bytesPerSecond: 100, gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
});
```

Comment: I'll try it and give you a feedback, if changing these options did help. I'm just wondering, if there is a better way to discover the real problem.

Comment: @JimyWeiss The default values for these settings are set to proper values to optimize resource usage (see OSI model Session layer). There are some countries where the internet speed and connections (especially the upload speed) are unstable. Unfortunately, some governments set many restrictions and configurations on the internet, resulting in many apps not working there properly and strange network behaviors.

Comment: Unfortunately, these measures did not help at all.

Comment: @JimyWeiss So it may depend on your environment if the connection is not closed by your .Net app. Try to monitor your server network.